# Código com if e else não funciona

Tags: c, if, else

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
main()
{

int n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, ma, mp, mav, mev, dp, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, i, maior, menor;


printf("Escolha a operação que deseja efetuar: Média Aritmética Simples(1), Média Ponderada(2), Desvio Padrão(3), Maior Valor(4) ou Menor Valor(5)");
scanf("%d", i);



if(i == 1) {
printf("Digite o primeiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("Digite o segundo número: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);
printf("Digite o terceiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n3);
printf("Digite o quarto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n4);
printf("Digite o quinto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n5);

                  ma = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5)/5;
                  printf("A Média Aritmética Simples é: %d", ma);
}


else if(i == 2) {
printf("Digite o primeiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("Digite o segundo número: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);
printf("Digite o terceiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n3);
printf("Digite o quarto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n4);
printf("Digite o quinto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n5);

                printf("Digite os respectivos pesos: ");
                scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &p1, &p2, &p3, &p4, &p5);
                mp = (n1*p1) + (n2*p2) + (n3*p3) + (n4*p4) + (n5*p5);
                mp = mp/(p1+p1+p3+p4+p5);
                printf("A Média Ponderada é: %d", mp);
}




else if(i == 3) {
printf("Digite o primeiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("Digite o segundo número: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);
printf("Digite o terceiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n3);
printf("Digite o quarto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n4);
printf("Digite o quinto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n5);
            dp = sqrt(pow(n1-ma , 2) + pow(n2-ma , 2) + pow(n3-ma, 2) + pow(n4-ma, 2) + pow(n5-ma, 2));
            dp = dp/5;
            printf("O Desvio Padrão é: %d", dp);

}



else if(i == 4) {
printf("Digite o primeiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("Digite o segundo número: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);
printf("Digite o terceiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n3);
printf("Digite o quarto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n4);
printf("Digite o quinto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n5);

                if(n1>n2) {maior = n1; }
                else{maior = n2;}
                if(maior < n3) { maior = n3;}
                if(maior < n4) {maior = n4;}
                if(maior < n5) {maior = n5;}

                printf("O maior número é: %d", maior);
}




else if(i == 5)   {
printf("Digite o primeiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n1);
printf("Digite o segundo número: ");
scanf("%d", &n2);
printf("Digite o terceiro número: ");
scanf("%d", &n3);
printf("Digite o quarto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n4);
printf("Digite o quinto número: ");
scanf("%d", &n5);



                 if(n1 < n2){ menor = n1;}
                 else{ menor = n2;}
                 if(menor > n3){ menor = n3;}
                 if(menor > n4){ menor = n4; }
                 if(menor > n5){ menor = n5;}

                printf("O menor número é: %d", menor);
}
else { printf("Impossíve!");}





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá existe um erro simples no seu código:

```
scanf("%d", &i);
```

Precisa do "&" para referenciar o endereço de memoria da variável "i". O & só não é obrigatório quando trabalhamos com ponteiro. Espero ter ajudado!

O erro portanto não é no if e else. É na leitura da entrada.